# How to get a onClick to work in a row - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get a click even to work with a table in `reactjs`.  My first attempt was to make the whole row clickable.  Here is my code:

```
var UserList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return getUsers();
  },
  handleClick: function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
  },
  render: function() {
    var users = this.state.users.map(function(user) {
      return (
        <tr onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <td>{user.name}</td>
          <td>{user.age}</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Full Detail</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
              {users}
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This did not work.  I then tried to add a button in the table:

```
<button className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>Full Detail</button>
```

That also did not work.  I have other `onClick`'s working throughout my app, but how do I make this work with a table?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your problem is the function of user that creates the table row is not bound to your react component. The value of `this` will not be your react component and handleClick will not exist as a property of `this`.

Try

```
var users = this.state.users.map(function(user) {
  return (
    <tr onClick={this.handleClick}>
      <td>{user.name}</td>
      <td>{user.age}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  );}.bind(this);
});
```

Or use Underscore's *bind* if you want it to work on all browsers.

Comment: That completely makes sense.  I didn't understand the last statement, "Or user underscore bind if you want it to work on all browsers"?  Can you show me an example of that?

Comment: .bind is not supported in older browsers. Underscore is a popular library that, among many things, adds bind support for older browsers.

Comment: Also if you would like to know which user row was clicked you add it as another parameter to bind: `.bind(this, user)`, and modify the click handler to: `handleClick: function (user, e) {`.

Comment: Thanks for this, sorry its old but to add to @joakimbeng solution, on the onclick it should look like this: `onClick={ (e) => this.props.onSelect(e, user)}`

Answer (score 5):

I'm new to react. How about this? You just wrap it in another function, then that function holds the closure scope and it calls it correctly.

No idea if this is bad practice or the performance difference, but it seems to work...

```
var users = this.state.users.map(function(user) {
  return (
    <tr onClick={()=>this.handleClick(user)}>
      <td>{user.name}</td>
      <td>{user.age}</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  );}.bind(this);
});
```

Comment: turns out this is bad practice in general, but especially in a dataset with significant amount of rows as n number of functions are built when only one would suffice. I will leave it up though as an example of what not to do

Comment: adding new function in child props on every render is a bad practice as this will mutate the virtual dom state on every render. So react have to re render the child component (tr) on every render of parent (table).

Answer (score 0):

Binding creates a new object. Thus if you bind your function for N employees, you are inefficiently creating N new functions. A more elegant approach is to bind the function once, and pass a reference to every row. Your original code was quite close. This is what I would suggest:

```
 handleClick = e => {
    const user = this.state.users.find(u => u.uuid == e.target.dataset.uui)
    console.log("clicked");
  },
  render() {
    return(
      <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Full Detail</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.users.map(user => 
                (
                 <tr data-uuid={user.uuid} onClick={this.handleClick}>
                   <td>{user.name}</td>
                   <td>{user.age}</td>
                    <td>{user.details || ''}</td>      
                 </tr>
                )
              )}
  
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```